# If $f(n) = \prod_{d|n} g(d)$, how can I get $g(n)$?

Tags: functions, arithmetic

If $f(n) = \prod_{d|n} g(d)$, how can to get $g(n)$?

Comment: My first comment was a bit too hasty. I think you should take a $\log$ of both sides, rename the functions, use Mobius Inversion, and then exponentiate. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula

Comment: What do you precisely mean? :)

Comment: So products are tough to work with in general. Lets take a $\log$ of both sides in order to turn that product into a sum. We would have $\log f = \Sigma \log g$. You don't have to rename them, but if you wanted to do so for the sake of what follows, you could declare $\hat{f}=\log f$ and $\hat{g} = \log g$. But then you can just apply the Mobius Inversion Formula (see the Wikipedia link) in order to "swap" the roles of $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{g}$. You aren't interested in $\hat{g}=\log g$, so you should exponentiate both sides to recover $g$.